# Meteor - Dynamic page with Owl carousel 2 , after refresh the page , the Owl carousel will break

Tags: meteor, owl-carousel-2

I'm having the displaying problem with jquery OwlCarousel2, 
all of data contexts is sent by Iron-router into the template.

sometimes the UI works normally sometimes does not working.
if I ever try to refresh the page , the Carousel will be broken.

here is the 15 sec video demo, so can see the display problem clearly.
[UI Problem - OwlCarousel2 and Meteor2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onp6DuxbRR4)

I've been trying so many different way to solve this problem by using Meteor.defer( ) or Meteor.setTimeout( ) and others, after struggling with this problem for more then 10 days still don't have any luck. please help me out with this. thank you guys very much in advance.

collection.js

```
Albums = new Mongo.Collection('albums');
```

routes.js

```
Router.route('/album/:slug', function () {
  this.render('AlbumSingal', {
    data: function () {
      return Albums.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
    }
  },);
});
```

AlbumSingal.html

```
<template name="AlbumSingal">
    {{ > OwlCarousel}}

    {{> IntroSection}}

    {{> PhotoBook}}

    {{> Tips}}

    {{> LinkToOtherAlbums}}
</template>
```

OwlCarousel.html

```
<template name="OwlCarousel">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        {{#each carouselImages}}
        <div class="item"><img src="/img/{{imageUrl}}" alt="{{imageUrl}}"></div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

OwlCarousel.js

```
Template.OwlCarousel.onRendered(function(){

    Meteor.defer(function(){

            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(
                {
                     margin:0,
                     loop:true,
                     autoplay:true,
                     autoplayTimeout:1500,
                     autoplaySpeed:1000,
                     autoplayHoverPause:true,
                     autoWidth:true,
                     items:4,
                     nav:true,
                     navText: [
                      '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                      '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
                     ]
                }
            );

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed with owl carousel that when you are using it with a `{{#each}}` or with dynamic data, it takes a while to load, so probably when it finishes rendering, the `"$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({});"` already was loaded with nothing (since .owl-carousel didn't exists at the time).

What happened to me was that `"$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({});"` loaded with only the static elements and didn't get any of my ".item" elements.

You can try to solve that by putting the `"$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({});"` function inside the `.js` that calls the template and setting a interval of 200ms or less if works for you.

Comment: thank you for helping me with this.
I've tried the same method as you mentioned here, it worked...... but kind of half way only, when the internet downloading speed is too slow,  this will be broken as well. 

still looking for the better solution. :'D

Answer (score 0):

you can create template for the image which is to be shown in the carousel and on the onRendered of that template, trigger owl carousel, So, when your images are fetched, then only the owl carousel will trigger.